# PHP: Insert array data into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following array named $people and this is the output I get with a print_r():

> Array (
>
> [0] => "Zyzz","fitness","21","Male"
>
> [1] => "Arnold","bodybuilder","23","Male"
>
> [2] => "Jeff","fitness","19","Male"
>
> )

How can I insert these values to my MySQL Database?

I have a vague idea wich is:

> $sql=" INSERT INTO famous (name,type,age,sex) VALUES ($people)";
>
> mysql_query($sql);

How can I accomplish this correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure that is your pint_r()????

Answer (score 0):

What if you made a foreach loop like

```
foreach($people as $person)
```

And then used the $person variable in your query.  The foreach will just iterate your array.  However, the values of your array don't seem right.  Are you sure that is the exact print_r?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO famous (name,type,age,sex) VALUES ";
foreach($people as $p)
{
$sql .= '('.$p.'),';
}
$sql = rtrim($sql,',');
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: @Brett Zamir Thx correction!! Can u tell me how to make new line in this editor. I just use <br> for new line

Comment: Hi I think this doesn't work, if I echo the $sql statement I get [...] VALUES ("Zyzz","fitness","21","Male")("Arnold","bodybuilder","23","Male") ("Jeff","fitness","19","Male")

Comment: So it's not a valid query, remember that each "value" goes in a different column

Comment: There is a comma seprator between them check it out

Comment: VALUES ("Zyzz","fitness","21","Male"),("Arnold","bodybuilder","23","Male") ,("Jeff","fitness","19","Male")

Comment: @Jain: Just hit enter. It already had line breaks; it just needed the `<br>`'s removed. But to highlight code, you need to indent each line or use the button when highlighting the text to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
foreach($people as &$person) {
    $person = '('.$person.')';
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO famous (name,type,age,sex) VALUES " . implode (",", $people);
mysql_query($sql);
```